# Compiling and running camera-app with Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, camera, cross-compilation

Got camera-app, revno: 542.
Host - 14.04, Ubuntu SDK.

### Target Desktop

getting runtime qml error when trying to run the 'camera' run configuration:

```
file:///home/user/camera-app/camera-app.dev/camera-app.qml:24:1: module "CameraApp" is not installed 
     import CameraApp 0.1 
     ^
```

### Target ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386

getting packager error when trying to run the 'camera' run configuration:

```
Could not find the manifest.json file in /home/user/camera-app/build-camera-app.dev-UbuntuSDK_for_i386_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_14_04_trusty-Default/.ubuntu-sdk-deploy.
```

### Target ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386 -DCLICK_MODE=on

(with cmake options '-DINSTALL_TESTS=off -DCLICK_MODE=on')

getting wrong architecture in package configs when trying to run 'camera' run configuration:

```
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Sdk-Launcher> Executing:     /tmp/com.ubuntu.camera_3.0.0.latest_armhf.click
Sdk-Launcher> Force Install: False
Sdk-Launcher> Skip Uninstall:False
Sdk-Launcher> Launcher PID: 32296
Sdk-Launcher> Installing application .....
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Waiting for authentication
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Results:
Fatal error: /tmp/com.ubuntu.camera_3.0.0.latest_armhf.click failed to install.
WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /tmp/com.ubuntu.camera_3.0.0.latest_armhf.click: Package architecture "armhf" not compatible with system architecture "i386"

Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed
```

After editing the initial manifest.json to have i386 architecture, the package can be installed. But there is a runtime error:

```
Debug-helper> Setting up environment
Debug-helper> TmpDir:      /home/phablet/.local/share/com.ubuntu.camera/
Debug-helper> AppId:       com.ubuntu.camera_camera_3.0.0.latest
Debug-helper> Environment: confined
Debug-helper> Environment initialized, starting the application
Debug-helper> Executing ./camera-app['./camera-app']
./camera-app: symbol lookup error: ./camera-app: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

### Target ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf -DCLICK_MODE=on

(with cmake options '-DINSTALL_TESTS=off -DCLICK_MODE=on')

Runs the app, but slowly.

What can I do to get something running on Desktop or on the sdk-14.04-i386?

ubuntu-terminal-app works for me on ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386 out of box.

Answer (score 0):

This message:

./camera-app: symbol lookup error: ./camera-app: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev

makes me believe you compiled it with a 15.04 Kit and are trying to run on a 14.10/RTM device/emulator.

Try again with either both on 15.05 or both on 14.10.